# "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow" on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-20.04

I have been trying to install Tensorflow on my Raspberry Pi but I always get the same error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2.0
```

The Raspberry Pi is running on Ubuntu-20.04 64-bit, I have Python 3.8.5 and 3.7.10 both are 64-bit too and pip3 version 21.0.1

I have tried getting different tf versions, using pip or pip3, installed a thousand different dependencies, with and without a virtual environment, and I have also tried installing from source. But always no matter what I try I get the same error or `"...".whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Does anyone know what I can do to get over these errors? is it even possible to install TensorFlow on my Rasberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be installing the correct version of Tensorflow. Raspberry Pi runs on an ARM CPU "armhf" and not regular x86 or amd64 or even arm64. To install correct version of tensorflow in RPi, do

```
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
```

and then,

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

Comment: I have already installed libatlas-base-dev, and again I'm getting the same error when doing `pip3 install tensorflow` this is the error I get `pip3 install tensorflow Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

Comment: Does [this article](https://itnext.io/installing-tensorflow-2-3-0-for-raspberry-pi3-4-debian-buster-11447cb31fc4#:~:text=Step%200%3A%20Check%20Raspberry%20Pi,) help?